# Showing a UIAlertAction based on UNUserNotification iOS not working as expected

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10

I have been at this for hours, and supposedly I have everything acting as it should be, but it is not calling my `userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
      willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
        withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))` method when notification goes off within the app, nothing happens at all.

The app gives a notification as expected when not in the app, but nothing while in.

Here is my code, if you can see something I'm doing wrong, please tell me.

Class NotificationDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>

@interface NotificationDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenter <UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
   willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
     withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler;

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
     withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler;

@end
```

NotificationDelegate.m:

```
#import "NotificationDelegate.h"

@implementation NotificationDelegate


//Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
      willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
        withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{

    NSLog(@"User Info : %@",notification.request.content.userInfo);
    [self sendMessage:[UIApplication sharedApplication] message:notification.request.content];
    completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}

- (void) sendMessage:(UIApplication *)application message:(UNNotificationContent *)content{
    UIAlertController *ac = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:content.title                  
                                                   message:content.body
                                                     preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Go Away!" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];

    [ac addAction:action];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [application.keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:ac animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
}

//Called to let your app know which action was selected by the user for a given notification.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
        withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"User Info : %@",response.notification.request.content.userInfo);
}

@end
```

AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "NotificationDelegate.h"
@import UserNotifications;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UNUserNotificationCenter *center;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NotificationDelegate *ncdel;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@import UserNotifications;

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    self.center.delegate = self.ncdel;    
    return YES;
}
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.pvHelper = [[PickerViewHelperViewController alloc] init];
    self.pickerView.dataSource = self.pvHelper;
    self.pickerView.delegate = self.pvHelper;
    self.pvHelper.answer = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:10];

}

- (void) requestPermission{
    UNAuthorizationOptions options = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionSound + UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:options
                          completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                              if (!granted) {
                                  NSLog(@"Something went wrong");
                              }
                          }];
}


- (void) createNotification:(NSNumber *)time{
    UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
    content.title = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Alarming, isn't it?" arguments:nil];
    content.body = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Listen to me my love" arguments:nil];
    content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
    content.badge = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:99];

    UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger triggerWithTimeInterval:[time integerValue]
                                                                                                    repeats:NO];

    //Note: Calling addNotificationRequest with the same identifier string will replace the existing notification. If you want to schedule multiple requests use a different identifier each time.
    NSString *identifier = @"Alarm Triggered";
    UNNotificationRequest *req = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:identifier content:content trigger:trigger];
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    [center addNotificationRequest:req withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if(error != nil){
            NSLog(@"Something went wrong: %@", error);
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"I have requested the Notification be made");
        }

    }];




}

- (IBAction)buttonTappedSetAlarm:(id)sender {
    [self requestPermission];

    [self createNotification: [[self pvHelper] answer]];
}
```

It doesn't matter much to this but my single view app just has a picker for 10,20,30...60 seconds,minutes,hours, and I do the math to get the time for the requests.

So like I said, the request work outside the application as expected, but with the app in the foreground, nothing occurs, and it's really bothering me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do it.

I got rid of trying to implement the `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` in another class and just did it in my View Controller:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "PickerViewHelperViewController.h"
@import UserNotifications;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;

@property (strong, nonatomic) PickerViewHelperViewController *pvHelper;

// Two methods needed to implement from the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler;

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler;

@end
```

and then just had the accompanying code within my .m file to present a local notification.

```
- (void) sendMessage:(UIApplication *)application title:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message{
    UIAlertController *ac = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title
                                                                message:message
                                                         preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *action = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Go Away!" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];

    [ac addAction:action];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [application.keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:ac animated:YES completion:^{
            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
        }];
    });
}

//Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
      willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
        withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{

    NSLog(@"User Info : %@",notification.request.content.userInfo);
    [self sendMessage:[UIApplication sharedApplication] title:@"local notification within App" message:notification.request.content.body];
    completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}

//Called when a notification is delivered to a background app.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
        withCompletionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"User Info : %@",response.notification.request.content.userInfo);
    [self sendMessage:[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                title:@"I habe been opened from outside the App"
              message:response.notification.request.content.body];
    completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}
```

my create notification and ask for permission methods above remained unchanged in the code.

This allowed for a local notification to appear within the app and for a notification to appear if the app was opened via the notification.